# How to access the last part of a GET url in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm building my link like this:

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Icon->fa('plus'),
    ['controller' => 'Questions', 'action' => 'add', $questionnaire->id],
    [
        'title' => 'Add'
    ]
);
```

This creates the desired icon on my browser, with this link:

```
<host>/questionnaire/questions/add/2
```

On the "other side", by using for example

```
$this->request->getParam('action')
```

I can correctly get `"add"` as a value.

But how can I access the `2`, so the last part of the url?

I've tried with

```
$this->request->getQueryParams()
```

and it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your connected routes. If there is a corresponding route that has a route element defined for that value, eg

```
/questionnaire/questions/add/:id
```

then you could get the value via that element name, `getParam('id')`.

If the corresponding route does not have a dedicated named element for that value, but instead a `*`, which is the default for fallback routes connected via `fallbacks()`, then it will land in the `pass` parameter, `getParam('pass')`, which is an array of trailing values, and your value would sit at index `0`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Request Parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Route Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Passed Arguments](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments)**